# ASP.NET CORE HttpContext.Session variables returning random null values

Tags: asp.net-core, google-cloud-platform

I have developed ASP.NET core MVC application where I would like to access session variables like this:

```
var currentProject = HttpContext.Session.GetString("CurrentProject");
```

If I run this locally on my machine, currentProject is never null, however if I host this application on GCP CloudRun, from time to time I run into situation where currentProject = null; It happens absolutely randomly - I can run my app successfuly 100 times, and then suddenly one day I got null value 5 times in the row, and in the 6th time it works again. And this repeats from time to time.
Any ideas, what could be the reason for it?

Here is part of my configuration, maybe this might give some ideas:

```
 var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
 builder.Services.AddSession();
 builder.Services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
 {
     options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;
     options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
 });
 app.UseSession();
```

Comment: Session data can go away for tonnes of reasons. If the app restarts, or if the session expires for example. Try capturing session start/end events.

Comment: @DavidG Thank you for answering. This seems to be more complicated that I thought.

Comment: Probably you need to persist Session (in case the app is restarted) using one of the approach found in [Distributed caching in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed?view=aspnetcore-7.0). In case, for performance reasons, you could have multiple instance of the app running, you could also consider the *sticky sessions* approach (see [Session and state management in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-7.0#session-state)).

Answer (score 1):

Posting this as a community wiki to help other community members that can encounter this issue.

As stated by @DavidG:

> Session data can go away for tonnes of reasons. If the app restarts,
> or if the session expires for example. Try capturing session start/end
> events.

The point of checking it is to prevent your page from throwing a ugly `NullReferenceException` in case the session is null. This, if you check if it is null, you can renew your page's session, or redirect to a login page, for example.